# Oracle select query conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a search jsp, which has more than one criteria( ID OR NAME OR DATE OR ...) for searching the database. I need a single select query to satisfy all the condition. I have written the select query partially, but it is not working well. Please help me in finishing the query

```
   select * from table 1
   where Id in ( select id from table 1 where ( those three conditions here)

   i have (1=? or id=?)
         and (1=? or name=?)
         and (1=? or date =?)
```

but it returns the full table. I know those three condition returns true. How to modify that in order to obtain the result. I don't want any stored procedure, as i am a newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a redundant subquery.

I assume the first parameter will be `1` if the second parameter is null, and `0` if the second parameter is not null; likewise the 3rd parameter will `1` if the 4th parameter is null, and `0` if the 4th parameter is not null, etc.?

Try this:

```
select * from table
where (1=? or id=?)
     and (1=? or name=?)
     and (1=? or date =?)
```

For example, if the user was searching by name I'd expect the parameters to be something like `(1,NULL,0,'SMITH',1,NULL)`.

(Also, you can't use `1` for the table alias.)

Answer (score 1):

If your conditions are true for every row, you'll get the full table.

For example, if your variable is `1`, `1 = 1` will be true, and every row will be returned.

p,s, I don't understand why you've nested the select.

Comment: <br/>I got your point. I need to fetch the full data if all the values of id name and date are null, else i need to get data for the given criteria.


How to modify the condition to meet the requirement? I tried with id alone by sending a vale for id. It always return full table as it returns True, for the condition.
Yes i am always sending 1.

Comment: The outer query involves more than one table. Id is the foreign key.  The inner query is to get all the ids.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table 1
   where Id in ( select 
         (case 
               when (1=? or id=?) and (1=? or name=? )  and (1=? or date =?) then id
          end) as id from table 1 )
```

I hope this is what you are looking for